# Importing library 'RPA.Browser.Selenium' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPA'

Tags: python, docker, selenium, robotframework

**I am getting the below error while running the robot file in a docker self hosted environment in ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/usr/src/project/tasks.robot' on line 3: Importing library 'RPA.Browser.Selenium' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPA'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  None

PYTHONPATH:

  /usr/local/bin

  /usr/lib/python36.zip

  /usr/lib/python3.6

  /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload

  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Comment: Please provide a [Reproduciple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so people can help instead of simply quess what could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by the PyCharm was to install 'RPA' with:
*pip install rpa* 
Even with it installed the problem kept the same. What really worked was installing the rpaframework:
*pip install rpaframework*

Answer (score 0):

This was solved,i just had to change the version of rpaframework to the latest one in the conda.yaml file and the issue was resolved.